Visiting the USA before start of J1
My son has a J1 visa as he intends to work as a camp councillor in the US. Before starting work he wants to visit Hawaii then go to Canada for a few weeks. The J1 says multiple entry. Will he be able to enter Hawaii on his J1, leave and then come back in during his 30 days before the start of camp, or does he need to enter Hawaii on a tourist visa (B2?) and then the J1 for his second entry? Or is this just not possible?

Depending on your son's nationality, he might be able to use ESTA for the first visit instead of a B visa.

He wouldn't be able to enter Hawaii on J1 because he can only enter on J1 up to 30 days before the employment actually starts. He'll need to use a tourist visa.
If the first entry is within the 30 days (i.e.: few weeks is <4) then it may be possible, but still at the discretion of the CBP officer in Hawaii.
